# CakePHP Error: Class 'appModel' not found

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I have been working on the same CakePHP application for several months (no version migrations) and have recently run into an error that I can't seem to find any reason for its cause. The error message says it comes from line 4 of this file (Comment.php)

```
class Comment extends appModel {

var $actsAs = array(
    'Containable'
);

var $belongsTo = 'Core';

public $validate = array(
    'author'    => array(
        'rule'=>'notEmpty'
    ),
    'body'  => array(
        'rule'=>'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'You cannot leave a blank comment'
    )
);
}
```

This comes up only when attempting to load the model:

```
Controller::loadModel('Comment');
```

For some context, each Core model relates to a form which can be commented on. The comments are related to the Core model via foreign key relation core_id. Each Core relates to only a single form and can have any number of comments.

The only other solutions to similar problems I can find were caused by migrating from one version of cake to another but I have been using the same version since beginning the project.

Comment: Would you please check whether there is App::uses('AppModel', 'Model'); at the top of 'Comment' model

Comment: There is no App::uses declaration at the top of the Comment model, but I have solved the problem which was caused by a typo of 'appModel' rather than 'AppModel'. Do I also need to put the App::uses call in for a different reason?

Comment: If it works fine at your version, then it is ok. But from version 2.1, that will be required. See migration guide for more information. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-1-migration-guide.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
```

at the top of the comment model.

and start comment model as follows:

```
class Comment extends AppModel {
```

Capital 'A', not small 'a'.

Comment: Thank you, it seems I didn't notice the lower case 'a'. That is what was causing the problem.